# Vulkan image layout transition using render pass

Tags: graphics, vulkan

I have a Vulkan renderer where a new render pass is started at the beginning of each frame. Then the command buffer is passed to several modules each of which submits some draw calls and other commands. Before the draw calls are submitted, it checks whether any additional textures have to be loaded which it does, at the end of the loading process an image layout transition to VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL is performed.

The problem is that the layout transition uses a vkCmdPipelineBarrier command which only allows same format for input and output ( VUID-vkCmdPipelineBarrier-oldLayout-01181 ) which makes the transition useless for me.

My only solution at the moment is to move the layout transitions to a different command buffer and submit it to the command queue separately, then retrieve the result before continuing building my command buffer, but that means I have to wait for all previous commands in the queue to finish, right?

Can you imagine a cleaner solution for performing layout transitions between different layouts during an active render pass?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

> My only solution at the moment is to move the layout transitions to a different command buffer and submit it to the command queue separately, then retrieve the result before continuing building my command buffer, but that means I have to wait for all previous commands in the queue to finish, right?

You're not thinking fourth dimensionally.

The order you *build* the command buffers in is irrelevant. What matters is the order you *submit* them in.

The code which is building your rendering command buffer can also be building a transfer command buffer. You write your rendering command assuming the images are in the correct layout, and you write transfer commands which *put* those images into the right layout after the transfer is complete. The order you write these commands is irrelevant; the only order that matters is their *submission* order. Put one CB before the other in that order, and (barriers willing) they will execute appropriately in that order.

The CPU never needs to wait on anything. No "results" need to be retrieved; that's the GPU's job.

Being able to do this is why you have to *tell* Vulkan what the layout of each image is anytime you try to use it.

Comment: So what you're basically saying is I should replace the memory barriers by commands of type, say, vkCmdCopyBufferToImage which I can use in the draw command buffer during a render pass?

Comment: You cannot use a copy operation (or any transfer operation) during a render pass. I said to create a *second command buffer* to build your transfer/barrier operations in, then submit them so that this second command buffer executes *first*.

Comment: I already use a second buffer, but there is some stalling. But I think I know what the problem is: The code from the example executes a vkQueueWaitIdle directly after the barrier so it can deallocate the second command buffer immediately. This of course means that every time I make a transition the program has to wait for everything in the queue to finish.

Comment: "*The code from the example*" Let this be a lesson to you: never blindly copy example code. In fact, never *copy* example code. Example code is almost never good code. It's meant to demonstrate how a thing works, not explain best practices.